# CSS making an element entirely move out of visible screen?

Tags: css

suppose i have a div, i want it to be out of visible area of computer monitor screen, so that when i use CSS transitions to move it to a specific position, an effect of element moving in slowly from outside of screen is created, and i also would like to create its reverse effect.

Comment: Use `position: absolute; left: -10000px;`? Or is there some complexity here that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DZFtt/

```
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="example2"></div>
<div id="example3"></div>
```

​

```
#example{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #386a95;
    position:relative; /*Not moved*/
}
#example2{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: rgb(177, 35, 35);
    position:relative;
    left:-25px; /*Pushed halfway off the screen*/
}
#example3{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    left:-50px; /*This is now totally hidden from view*/
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

`position: absolute;` then do something like `left: -100px;`

working example(hover over the box and wait): http://jsfiddle.net/fDnPj/

Answer (score 0):

IF you know the width of the div you can use the combination of position and left property like this

```
#my-div {
    position:absolute;    
    left:-100px;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

<div id="my-div">Hello</div>​
```

[Play here](http://jsfiddle.net/YMW3X/1/) by adjusting the left property.
​